# Using Stax Parser giving NULL while reading large XML File

Tags: java, xml

```
I am working on StaxParser and want to read a xml file.
```

I have used following code:

```
    public class StaxParserDemo {
        public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
        List<PLQ22> plqList = new ArrayList<>();
        PLQ22 currEmp = null;
        String tagContent = null;
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/home/vipul/Documents/config.xml"));

        while(reader.hasNext()){
          int event = reader.next();

          switch(event){
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: 
              if ("EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                currEmp = new PLQ22();
             }

              break;

            case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
              tagContent = reader.getText().trim();
              break;

            case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
              switch(reader.getLocalName()){
                case "EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter":
                    plqList.add(currEmp);
                 //   currEmp.Auto_Start=tagContent;

                  break;
                case "Barcode_Length":
                  currEmp.Barcode_Length = tagContent;
tagContent=null;                  
break;
                case "Lower_Barcode_length":
                  currEmp.Lower_Barcode_length = tagContent;
tagContent=null;                
  break;
                case "Upper_Barcode_Length":
                  currEmp.Upper_Barcode_Length = tagContent;
tagContent=null;                
  break;
              }
       if ("EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
            currEmp = null;
         }
              break;

            case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
              plqList = new ArrayList<>();
              break;
          }

        }


        for ( PLQ22 emp : plqList){
          System.out.println(emp);
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
    }
    class PLQ22{

        String Auto_Start;
      String Barcode_Length;
      String Lower_Barcode_length;
      String Upper_Barcode_Length;

      @Override
      public String toString(){
        return Barcode_Length+" "+Lower_Barcode_length+" "+Upper_Barcode_Length;
      }
    }
```

I have a very large config.xml file it has many nodes but I want to read values of EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter node.

It is gives me multiple null values after that I get the values that I actually want.

The xml file is something like this :

```
<ACU_Config_File>
  <ApplicationManager_Config>
    <ConsumerDisplay_Config>
      <Resolution>1366 x 768</Resolution>
    </ConsumerDisplay_Config>
    <Maintenance_Application>
      <Cash_Deposit_Report>ON</Cash_Deposit_Report>
      <Idle_Time>1</Idle_Time>
      <Lockout_Time>1</Lockout_Time>
      <ATM_EXE_NAME>ATM</ATM_EXE_NAME>
      <ATM_PATH>C:\Program Files\Forbes\Microbanker\Bin\ATM.exe</ATM_PATH>
    </Maintenance_Application>
    <ReportSettings_Config>
      <ChequeDeposit_ReportSettings>
        <EndorsementReportSettings_Config>
          <TransactionId Present="True" />
          <ChequeNo Present="True" />
          <Endorsement Present="False" />
        </EndorsementReportSettings_Config>
        <EndorsementSettings_Config Required="False">
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
<EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter>
        <Auto_Start>Start</Auto_Start>
        <Barcode_Length>7</Barcode_Length>
    <Lower_Barcode_length>14</Lower_Barcode_length>
    <Upper_Barcode_Length>13</Upper_Barcode_Length>
      </EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter>


.
.
.
.
<PassbookPrintingTimeOut>30</PassbookPrintingTimeOut>
      <InstructionTimeOut>30</InstructionTimeOut>
      <InsertChequeTimeOut>30</InsertChequeTimeOut>
      <SelectLanguageTimeOut>30</SelectLanguageTimeOut>
    </MFK_TIMERS_CONFIG>
  </MFK_ApplicationManager_Config>
</ACU_Config_File>
```

What changes I need to do in my code to not to get the null values and get the node values directly.

The output I am getting is something like this:

null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13
7 14 13

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What does it mean *"It is gives me multiple null values"*? The `reader` does not give you any null values.

Comment: Hello andreas I have edited the question and posted the actual output I am currently getting.

Comment: 1) Why are you creating `plqList` is two places? --- 2) You never clear the variables, so they may contain leftover values from previous iterations. You should clear them when done, e.g. when END_ELEMENT is "EpsonPLQ22_PassbookPrinter", set `currEmp = null`. --- 3) On any END_ELEMENT, set `tagContent = null` (after using it).

Comment: Could you share your complete XML? I ran your code with the XML fragment in the question, and I got the output as 7 14 13. Maybe there is some issue with you XML.

Comment: @GreenPadawan My xml file is too long...

Comment: Andreas I have done the changes as per your suggestion, now you can see the code I have edited.  Now I get the output like this null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
7 14 13
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null